# Escaping backslashes where they appear in a file when they don't always appear non-escaped

Tags: regex, csv, sed, escaping, weka

I've got a peculiar situation, I'm trying to import a CSV file into Weka and I've run into problems with Weka's apparently extremely poor ability to handle strings in a sanitary manner.

I'm already using sed to remove all non-ASCII characters but now I've run into a problem dealing with backslashes. The input I have contains escaped backslashes in some fields and non-escaped backslashes(which Weka cannot handle correctly) in others.

What I need is a regular expression that will find backslashes that are not preceded or followed by a backslash and add a second backslash. I'm having a real hard time making the syntax work and was wondering if someone could help me out.

Comment: would you please paste the part of the text or strings that you are working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following - `sed 's/\\\\/@@_@/g; s/\\/\\\\/g; s/@@_@/\\\\/g'`

Its replacing escaped backslashes with a token first, escape single backslashes and change tokens back to escaped backslashes.

Select a token that's not going to exist in the file.

```
echo 'asdfj\lasdf\\asldf\oweur\\lasjd;lf\\lasjfl\asdfsdf' | \
  sed 's/\\\\/@@_@/g; s/\\/\\\\/g; s/@@_@/\\\\/g'
```

Results:
`asdfj\\lasdf\\asldf\\oweur\\lasjd;lf\\lasjfl\\asdfsdf`

Another option - `sed 's/\([^\\]\)\(\\\)\([^\\]\)/\1\\\\\3/g'`

Comment: The first solution might be improved to avoid the unlikely event that a string `@@_@` could be falsely substituted to: `s/\\\\/\n/g;s/\\/&&/g;s/\n/\\\\/g'` the second solution does not cater for the edge cases when the single `\\` may be first or last character in a line. `sed -r 's/(^|[^\\\])\\\([^\\\]|$)/\1\\\\\2/g'` caters for these too.